Upgrade pre-installed python in Debian 12 running in Docker
I am running a docker container that uses python:3.9.19-slim as a base image. This image uses Debian 12 which I believe comes with python3.11 pre-installed. I saw this vulnerability report so want to update the python3.11 that is pre-installed to python3.11.5 or above, but I'm having some difficulties doing so. I added RUN apt -y upgrade python3 in my Dockerfile but that didn't change the python version.
When I run apt show python3 inside my container I get
Package: python3
Version: 3.11.2-1+b1

Update
I tried using python:3.11.9-slim and python:3.12.5-slim images but When I run apt show python3 inside my container I still get the same response. Not sure why this is the case
Package: python3
Version: 3.11.2-1+b1

Here are all the apt-get commands I have inside my docerfile
RUN apt update

RUN apt-get clean \
    && apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install nginx \
    && apt-get -y install python3-dev \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential


You’re using a base image (python:3.9.19-slim) that defaults to python 3.9, so running apt -y upgrade python3 won’t update it to Python 3.11.5 or higher. While one option is to upgrade Python from source, this can require many dependencies and significantly increase build time. A better approach is to switch to the official Python 3.11 Docker image, which ensures you have the latest version with minimal hassle and keeps your build process efficient.

not sure what you are doing but docker run -it python:3.11.9-slim python -V returns Python 3.11.9 for me.
Now if you try to 'upgrade' that image then you might get the default python version and that might be 3.11.5. Just don't try to upgrade!

It's not recommended to change the default version of python since it might break OS related scripts as mentioned here. Instead, you can use python:3.11.9-slim as the base image, which will have python3.11 as the default version of python.
If possible, you can also use the latest python image from Dockerhub which is python:3.12.5-slim

Event after update the base image to python:3.11.9-slim I stll get the same response when I run apt show python3 It shows python 3.11.2-1+b1 is installed

If you run docker run -itd --name python_container python:3.11.9-slim, and docker exec -it python_container bash, then you can see python --version shows the output as "Python 3.11.9". Also, check: apt list --installed | grep python.
